# Code is not working (C)

Tags: c

I want to calculate the wages with struct and arrays but it is not working. You will understand the exercise better when you see the code. For some reason if in `Wage` and `Days_Worked` I enter a number(100 and 2) 
`Wagered[i].Gross_Wage = Wagered[i].Wage * Wagered[i].Days_Worked;` Won't give me 200 but something else. Generally the programm won't work and I am trying to find the reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct User
{
    char First_Name[25];
    char Last_Name[25];
    int Wage, Days_Worked;
    int Tax;
    int Wage_Booking;
    int Net_Wage;
    int Gross_Wage;
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    int Wage_Summary = 0;
    struct User Wagered[1];

    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        /*printf("First Name: ");
        scanf("%s", &Wagered[i].First_Name);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Last Name: ");
        scanf("%s", &Wagered[i].Last_Name);
        printf("\n");*/

        printf("Wage: ");
        scanf("%d", &Wagered[i].Wage);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Days He Worked: ");
        scanf("%d", &Wagered[i].Days_Worked);
        printf("\n");

        Wagered[i].Gross_Wage = Wagered[i].Wage * Wagered[i].Days_Worked;
        Wagered[i].Wage_Booking = Wagered[i].Gross_Wage * 0.2;
        Wagered[i].Tax = (Wagered[i].Gross_Wage - Wagered[i].Wage_Booking) * 0.05;
        Wagered[i].Net_Wage = Wagered[i].Gross_Wage - Wagered[i].Wage_Booking - Wagered[i].Tax;
        Wage_Summary += Wagered[i].Net_Wage;
    }

    printf("The Summary of the Gross Wages is: %d\n", Wagered[i].Gross_Wage);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your problem description gets vague. What input do you supply? What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: For example if in &Wagered[i].Wage my input is 100 and in &Wagered[i].Days_Worked my input is 2, Wagered[i].Gross_Wage = Wagered[i].Wage * Wagered[i].Days_Worked; should be 200 but is not. Instead it gives me a 7-digit number and everytime I compile and run the 7-digit number will change. But still it will have 7 digits.

Comment: @ΔιονύσηςΤέρζιος edit your question and don't post comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement :

```
printf("The Summary of the Gross Wages is: %d\n", Wagered[i].Gross_Wage);
```

is *outside* your `for` loop. Therefore it will be executed when `i` has value `1`, thus accessing `Wagered[1].Gross_Wage`, which does not exist `Wagered[1]` is out of your array's bounds. Move it ***inside*** your `for` loop, like this :

```
for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    .
    .
    .

    Wagered[i].Gross_Wage = Wagered[i].Wage * Wagered[i].Days_Worked;
    Wagered[i].Wage_Booking = Wagered[i].Gross_Wage * 0.2;
    Wagered[i].Tax = (Wagered[i].Gross_Wage - Wagered[i].Wage_Booking) * 0.05;
    Wagered[i].Net_Wage = Wagered[i].Gross_Wage - Wagered[i].Wage_Booking - Wagered[i].Tax;
    Wage_Summary += Wagered[i].Net_Wage;

    printf("The Summary of the Gross Wages is: %d\n", Wagered[i].Gross_Wage);
}
```

and you will see the correct result printed.